# web api 2 can't get correct date value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

when Im trying to get an object from post method, I can't get the correct value of DateTime, my JSON:

```
{
        "JobRecord": [{
            "ShiftRecordID": 2,
            "JobDescriptionID": 0,
            "TaskDesciption": "Test task description",
            "WorkedWith": "I,G",
            "StartTime": "2015-02-06T07:30:00",
            "EndTime": "2015-02-06T09:00:00",
            "JobDescription": "Exit & Emergency Remedials",
            "JobNumber": 11939
        }],
    "EmployeeID": 1,
    "isCompanyCar": false
}
```

the value of the StartTime and EndTime always become 0001/01/01 00:00:00, anyone knows where is the problem? I stuck here like 2 days, can't find any relate solution.

Class definition

```
public class JobRecordJson
{
    public int JobDescriptionID { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public string WorkedWith { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompanyCar { get; set; }
    public DayType DayType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[ResponseType(typeof(JobRecord))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostJobRecord(JobRecordJson jobRecord)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(jobRecord);
        //DateTime.Parse(jobRecord.StartTime);
        // check if a shift record was created
        var shiftRecord = from r in db.ShiftRecords
                          where r.RecordDate == jobRecord.StartTime.Date && r.EmployeeID == jobRecord.EmployeeID
                          select r;
        try
        {
            int shiftRecordID;
            // if there isn't, create shift record first
            if (shiftRecord.Count() < 1)
            {

                int maxRecordID = db.ShiftRecords.Max(m => m.ID);
                ShiftRecord sr = new ShiftRecord()
                {
                    ID = maxRecordID + 1,
                    EmployeeID = jobRecord.EmployeeID,
                    IsCompanyVehicle = jobRecord.IsCompanyCar,
                    RecordDate = jobRecord.StartTime.Date,
                    DayType = jobRecord.DayType,
                    IsRead = false
                };
                db.ShiftRecords.Add(sr);
                db.SaveChanges();
                shiftRecordID = sr.ID;
            }
            else 
            {
                shiftRecordID = shiftRecord.First().ID;
            }
            // create job record
            int maxJobRecordID = db.JobRecords.Max(m => m.ID);
            JobRecord jr = new JobRecord()
            {
                ID = maxJobRecordID + 1,
                ShiftRecordID = shiftRecordID,
                JobDescriptionID = jobRecord.JobDescriptionID,
                TaskDesciption = jobRecord.TaskDescription,
                WorkedWith = jobRecord.WorkedWith,
                StartTime = jobRecord.StartTime,
                EndTime = jobRecord.EndTime,
            };
            db.JobRecords.Add(jr);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("There is an error: " + ex.ToString());
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        return Ok(jobRecord);
    }
```

Because I want to automatically create ShiftRecord if there isn't any ShiftRecord exist, so I create a class JobRecordJson (it's a DTO class, basically contains a JobRecord class and some extra information that I need). 
Once I get the JobRecordJson object, I will create JobRecord item and ShiftRecord (if necessary)

```
public class JobRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int JobDescriptionID { get; set; }
    public int ShiftRecordID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Task")]
    public string TaskDesciption { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Worked With")]
    public string WorkedWith { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Start Time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="End Time")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual JobDescription JobDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ShiftRecord ShiftRecord { get; set; }
}

public class ShiftRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Type")]
    public bool IsCompanyVehicle { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Day Type")]
    public DayType? DayType { get; set; }

    // properties below can only be operated by administrator
    [Display(Name = "Normal Hrs")]
    public decimal? NormalHours { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time And Half Hrs")]
    public decimal? TimeAndHalfHours { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Double Time Hrs")]
    public decimal? DoubleTimeHours { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Shift Hrs")]
    public decimal? ShiftHours { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Read?")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobRecord> JobRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think the StartTime and EndTime in C# code value is null.

Comment: show us your server side code. It looks like server does not retrieve your client data and uses its default values.

Comment: I upload the source code, and found the problem: the controller doesn't really get the JSON, all of the variables are null (or default value), but don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your json data structure, the default model binder can't bind that structure to the JobRecordJson.
You need to define your own custom model binder or change the json to something like this:

```
{
  "ShiftRecordID": 2,
  "JobDescriptionID": 12,
  "TaskDesciption": "Test task description",
  "WorkedWith": "I,G",
  "StartTime": "2015-02-06T07:30:00",
  "EndTime": "2015-02-06T09:00:00",
  "JobDescription": "Exit & Emergency Remedials",
  "JobNumber": 11939,
  "EmployeeID": 1,
  "isCompanyCar": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be your Json. can you try setting your property names to camel case?  Or even better create a web api method that returns an example of your object and see what it gives you back.

Likely reason property's are incorrect case:
Example "startTime":"2015-02-06..." Rather than "StartTime". It may be why all values are null.

If you are seeing a null object in your post , you may have an invalid structure, from what I can tell your Json should start:

{
   ...
  "startTime":"2015....
}

Comment: It was my bad, I post json with different format than the class, so it can't match I guess, problem solved now

Comment: Ah cool. If I get those issues creating a get with the same populated object to show the example Json.